# LINQ to XML: парсинг xml с отсутствующими тегами

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Есть некий xml. В целом его структура "постоянна", но есть узлы, в которых нет части тегов, которые необходимо считать.
Пример:

```
<row>
   <name>Name 1</name>
   <value>Value 1</value>
   <description>Description 1</description>
</row>
<row>
   <name>Name 2</name>
   <value>Value 2</value>
</row>
<row>
   <name>Name 3</name>
</row>
```

Т.е. считать не нужно поля `name, value, description`
Парсить пытаюсь следующим способом:

```
var objects = (from x in doc.Descendants("ROW")
   select new
      {
         name = x.Elements("name").FirstOrDefault().Value,
         value = x.Elements("value ").FirstOrDefault().Value,
         description= x.Elements("description").FirstOrDefault().Value
      }).ToList();
```

На выходе имею `System.NullReferenceException`
Думал получится по простому, но не получилось. Такая штука не проходит

```
description= x.Elements("description") == null ? null : x.Elements("description").FirstOrDefault().Value
```

Comment: имена не регистрозависимы?

Comment: думаю регистр не при чем. Проблема уходит стоит только добавить отсутствующие пары тегов.

Comment: 1. Почему `Elements`, а не `Element`? 2. Пробуйте так: `name = x.Element("name")?.Value`

Comment: > Такая штука не проходит. Потому что `Elements` возвращает не `null`, а пустую последовательность. Тогда уж надо проверять на null выражение `x.Elements("description").FirstOrDefault()`. Если уж оставите `Elements`, то пробуйте `x.Elements("description").FirstOrDefault()?.Value`

Comment: Капец я баран, спасибо. Это же реально список формируется .FirstOrDefault(). Вообщем, такая штука помогла x.Elements("description").FirstOrDefault() == null ? null :  x.Elements("description").FirstOrDefault().Value. Оформите как ответ

Comment: Используйте null propagation operator .FirstOrDefault()?.Value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Свойство `Elements` возвращает коллекцию элементов с указанным именем. Если таких элементов нет - возвращается *пустая коллекция*, а не `null`. Вам нужно проверять на `null` результат вызова `FirstOrDefault()`. А еще лучше использовать [метод `Element`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx) - он возвращает "первый (в порядке документа) дочерний элемент с указанным XName" или "null если нет элемента с указанным именем" (цитаты из MSDN). Т.е. его результат аналогичен вызову `Elements("name").FirstOrDefault()`.

Ну и теперь можно воспользоваться [оператором `?.`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
name = x.Element("name")?.Value
```

Если тега `name` не окажется - в `name` будет записано значение `null`. Если вместо `null` вам нужно какое-то другое значение по умолчанию, то воспользуйтесь еще и [оператором `??`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator):

```
name = x.Element("name")?.Value ?? "(не указано)"
```